# SQL / Teradata Query - Filter by fields while using multiple Inner Joins

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I need to query my database and bring this back:

```
| Policy Num | Coverage Code |
```

My current query returns everything for the year 2014 ( i.e. A row for each claim number with the attached coverage code)

> SELECT
>     SCHEMA.TABLE.POLICY_NUMBER,
>     P_FAR_BI_VW.V_CLAIM_SERVICE_TYP_DIM.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE
>
> FROM
>
> SCHEMA.TABLE
>
> INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE ON (SCHEMA.TABLE.POLICY_ID=SCHEMA.TABLE.POLICY_ID)
>
> INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE ON (SCHEMA.TABLE.SERVICE_TYPE_ID=SCHEMA.TABLE.SERVICE_TYPE_ID)
>
> INNER JOIN SCHEMA.TABLE ON (SCHEMA.TABLE.FISCAL_PERIOD_ID=SCHEMA.TABLE.FISCAL_PERIOD_ID  AND  SCHEMA.TABLE.YEAR_NUM  =  2014)

I have tried a few different ways of querying but I can't seem to get it to work. I have tried:

> SELECT
>     distinct(SCHEMA.TABLE.POLICY_NUMBER),
>     SCHEMA.TABLE.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE
>
> Inner Joins
>
> group by
>     SCHEMA.TABLE.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE

and other various ideas.  The Error I am getting in return is: `Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group`

I know there must be away to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select items must all be in your group by

```
SELECT distinct(SCHEMA.TABLE.POLICY_NUMBER)
     , SCHEMA.TABLE.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE

/* INNER JOINS */

GROUP BY  SCHEMA.TABLE.POLICY_NUMBER
       ,  SCHEMA.TABLE.COVERAGE_TYP_CDE;
```

Comment: Or simply remove the GROUP BY :-)